# Firebird 2.1 Issue with User and Role

Tags: stored-procedures, firebird, role, user-roles, firebird2.1

I am using FireBird 2.1 and I have a user and a role. I granted execute permission on an stored procedure to role but not to user.
When I am trying to execute the stored procedure while logged in as a user with the role, I am getting following error:

> Statement #1: no permission for execute access to PROCEDURE SPSELECTMANAGERS.

I checked the roles and users, the user is already added in the roles.

Comment: Are you logged in using the role? There are three parameters to login: user name, password, role.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the SP recursive? In that case the procedure must have granted right to execute itself, ie add this to the DB creation script:

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON PROCEDURE SPSELECTMANAGERS TO PROCEDURE SPSELECTMANAGERS;
```

BTW this behaviour is considered to be a bug and will be fixed in future version (FB 3).